# Jquery detect when end function and repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a function when an animation finishes. I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
function carrousel_header() {
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_1").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_2").delay(4000).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_3").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_4").delay(8000).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_5").delay(10000).fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_6").delay(12000).fadeIn(2000);

    setInterval(carrousel_header(),1500);
}
```

The idea is that the element show and hide themselves in a specific order. I need to be able to show/hide the next `<div>` after the last one has finished executing its animation.

```
<div id="web_header_ani_ele_content">
    <div id="web_header_ani_ele_1" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="web_header_ani_ele_2" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="web_header_ani_ele_3" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="web_header_ani_ele_4" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="web_header_ani_ele_5" style="display:none;""></div>
    <div id="web_header_ani_ele_6" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="web_header_ani_texto_1" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    carrousel_header();
</script>
```

**MY CODE FOR WORKS WITH MODIFICATION , I ADD NOW**

```
function carrousel_header()
{
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_1").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_2").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_3").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_4").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_5").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_6").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);


jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_1").hide(1);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_2").hide(1);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_3").hide(1);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_4").hide(1);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_5").hide(1);
jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_6").delay(2000).hide(1,function(){carrousel_header();});



//setInterval(carrousel_header,1500);

}
```

Comment: one simple reason is once elements are visible they can't fadeIn again unless you hide them

Comment: Also make yourself familiar with the [callback parameter of `fadeIn`](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/#callback-function) and [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/). They allow you to do things after one or multiple animations finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that you aren't calling `setInterval()` correctly.  You would need to change this:

```
setInterval(carrousel_header(),1500);
```

to this:

```
setInterval(carrousel_header,1500);
```

Including the parentheses tells JS to execute the function immediately and pass its return value to `setInterval()` (which is not what you want).  You just want to pass a function reference (without the parens).

Your second issue is that you aren't ever making the items not visible so repeatedly fading them in does nothing after the first time.  You will need to add code that fades them out or something like that.

---

Personally, I would probably using a completion function to trigger it and add an opposite function to fade them out like this:

```
function carrousel_header() {
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_1").delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_2").delay(4000).fadeIn(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_3").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_4").delay(8000).fadeIn(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_5").delay(10000).fadeIn(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_6").delay(12000).fadeIn(2000, carrousel_headerOut);
}

function carrousel_headerOut() {
     // customize each one of these to the individual timing that you want
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_1").fadeOut(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_2").fadeOut(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_3").fadeOut(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_4").fadeOut(2000);
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_5").fadeOut(2000);
     // call carrousel_header on the completion function of the longest animation
     jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_6").fadeOut(2000, carrousel_header);
}
```

This avoids the extra timer and avoids any small build-up in timing differences between your animations and your interval timer as it runs for a long time.

Comment: There still wouldn't be any visible changes, since all the elements are already visible after the first iteration. I'm not sure what repeating the animation is good for... but if the OP wants it.

Comment: I put ths you tell , but no chage nothing no repit other time

Comment: @user3765800 - you aren't ever hiding your objects so fading them in doesn't do anything once they are already visible.  Where's your code for hiding them?

Comment: @user3765800 - I added a fadeOut function that can be called after they all faded in.  You can customize that to work the way you want (your question didn't way how you want it to work).  The general idea is that you alternate between these two functions and you call them via the completion callback on the fade operation for the longest animation in each operation.

Comment: @FelixKling - I added a fadeOut operation which the OP can customize to their liking (since they didn't specify how they want it to work).

Comment: Ok , i modified my code and now works , you can see new code up , regards

Comment: @user3765800 - is that really what you want.  The moment they finish their `fadeIn()`, you hide them?  I offered you a version where you fade them out after they are all done fading in.  Also, you don't generally add your final code to your question here on StackOverflow.  Instead, you usually vote for the answer that helped you the most with the green checkmark to the left of the answer.